# Program-controlled keyboard & mouse inputs don't work with Mass Effect 1

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, windows, mass-effect

I use a program called [DS2Key](http://www.1emulation.com/forums/topic/34902-ds2key-svn-r52-released/) which allows me to control my computer with my Nintendo DS Lite. I typically use this setup to play GameCube games with Dolphin (my 'cube has long since died), but I'm trying to get it to work with other games- it works best with console ports, for obvious reasons. It works by simulating keypresses and mouse movements- it says it has PPJoy gamepad emulation support, but that doesn't seem to actually work.

Mass Effect 1, however, does not seem to like its inputs being controlled by another program. When ME1 is in the foreground, the computer does not respond to DS button presses or mouse movements. It works fine if I Alt-Tab to minimize the game, but I lose control again when I switch back.

Does anyone have any idea why this is, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just use a normal controller instead of using your DS?

Comment: @Frank I don't own one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, I realized the answer right after I asked the question.

I had Mass Effect set up to run as administrator, and Windows doesn't want non-privileged programs taking control of privileged ones. Good thinking, Microsoft. The answer to this or any similar problem is simply to run the control program as administrator as well. I suspect it'll also be able to answer UAC popups now too.